# Should I use the plural after a disjunctive "or"?

Tags: grammatical-number, logic

When using a disjunctive `or` with two alternatives, is it better to use the plural or the singular?

> A bike or a car are suitable vehicles for your journey.

vs

> A bike or a car is a suitable vehicle for your journey.

The second version is correct from a formal logic perspective but the plural version sounds better to my non-native English speaker's ear.

Comment: I wouldn't use either of these, as it sounds like you're saying only one of the two is a transport device with an omitted either at the beginning. I would say "Bikes and cars are modes of transport." (I've never heard transport devices used to describe vehicles)

Comment: @JohnClifford: I modified the example as the one I gave was indeed a bit strange. The logic is that a bike is OK, a car is OK but someone would use only one of them.

Comment: [This article by Jane Straus](http://www.grammarbook.com/grammar/subjectVerbAgree.asp) is quite clear.

Comment: Thanks for the update. As @EdwinAshworth says, that article should answer your question nicely.

Comment: Thank you, it is now clear. The article specifically states that *"Two singular subjects connected by or, either/or, or neither/nor require a singular verb."*. So logic wins. @EdwinAshworth - if you convert the comment into a question I will accept it promptly to have something if someone looks for the same question.

Comment: @WoJ Thank you, but the question is not really appropriate for ELU. The sister site ELL was added to SE to handle questions one might expect to be addressed in schools before the Sixth Form.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I looked up "Sixth Form" :) and I will flag my question to be moved to ELL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this situation, the numerical form of the subject(s) is technically vague.

You can avoid this situation altogether by using (*either* + *or*) or (*both* + *and*) and changing the tense accordingly. These devices completely eliminate all vagueness between the subject and verb tense, as 'either' is ALWAYS singular, and 'both' is ALWAYS plural.

Example (using *both* + *and*):

"**Both** bikes **and** cars **are** suitable vehicles for your journey."

or (using *either* + *or*):

"**Either** a bike **or** a car **is** a suitable vehicle for your journey."

Hope this clarifies a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You may use either.

*Or* should request a **singular**.

But as you have **more than one** device you may use, despite *or*, a **plural** because here the **alternative is less than an enumeration** of several objects.

The only rule would be for a *real* alternative with only one choice :
In your question both car & bike are vehicules ; but if - for ex. - you'd have put helmet instead of car in a question the **singular** is requested.

*"**Is** a bike **or** a helmet a suitable vehicle ?"*